# Crosstab multiple aggfunc has '_dummy_' error

Tags: pandas, aggregate, crosstab

The following code is from [Agg function for Crosstab][1]
It returns '*dummy*' error. How can I resolve this?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

c1 = np.repeat(['a','b'], [50, 50], axis=0)
c2 = list('xy'*50)
c3 = np.repeat(['G1','G2'], [50, 50], axis=0)
np.random.shuffle(c3)
c4=np.repeat([1,2], [50,50],axis=0)
np.random.shuffle(c4)
val = np.random.rand(100)

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':c1, 'c2':c2, 'c3':c3, 'c4':c4, 
'val':val})
print(df)
table  = pd.crosstab([df.c1,df.c2], [df.c3,df.c4], 
values=df.val, aggfunc=[len, np.mean])
print(table)
```

result:

```
Message='__dummy__'
line 14, in <module>
  table  = pd.crosstab([df.c1,df.c2], [df.c3,df.c4], values=df.val, aggfunc=[len, np.mean])
```

Comment: This provided code snippet runs as expected in `pandas 1.3.2`.

Comment: @HenryEcker were you able to get the  correct result? Is the format different for current pandas?

Comment: I didn't verify the averages and lens were correct against the source dataframe, but no error and it produced data for all the expected indices. I did not modify the code block in any way simply copied and ran.

Comment: Please print result of [`pd.show_versions()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.show_versions.html).

Comment: @Parfait. I have this error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.interval'

Comment: Try re-installing pandas. Though that error line looks like you build pandas from source code in a development version. If so, be sure to run at top level of pandas source code (assuming Cython is installed): `python setup.py build_ext --inplace -j 4`.